# Xamarin.Android No Debug Symbols File Was Found

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

If you are the same guy who read my last post earlier, well, yes, i am still stuck with runtime errors.

I just created a sample app, enabled **Proguard** and **SDK Assemblies Linking**. Then tried to run the app in **Release mode**. An exception was thrown :

> You are deploying an app supporting 'armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86' ABIs to an incompatible device of ABI 'x86'. You should either create an emulator matching one of your app's ABIs or add 'x86' to the list of ABIs your app builds for.

Amazing, right? So, went over to Project **Properties > Android Options > Advanced** and checked all of the **supported architectures**.

Now, in **release mode**, the app crashes inside the emulator(which is `Android_accelerated_x86_oreo`, by the way). And Visual Studio 2019 shows the following warnings :

> Directory obj\Release\81\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.dll but no debug symbols file was found

I have 19 similar warnings for `Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.dll` and 18 other dlls(I really wish nobody asks me to type all the dll names here).

So, anyone else faced this same issue? How do i get over this?

**Edit 1**

After deleting the **bin** and **obj** folder, re-building the project, there are no warnings anymore, but the app still crashes inside the `x86` emulator.

**Edit 2**

Changed **linking** to **None** and now app works fine. But apk size is too big.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Android Options** > **Debugging Options**. UNCKECK the **Enable Developer Instrumentation** box.

Clean and Deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Android has many types of ABI's eg : 'armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86'

Since you have a emulator that needs `x86` you might want to check it while making builds.

Go to Android Right click on **Project>Properties>Android Build>Advanced**  Once you reach there add the supporting ABI and you will be good to work with Release

Comment: As i said, i checked all supported architecture including `x86`. Please see my edit

Comment: Did you try individually building all the projects on the basis of dependency?

Comment: Um, how do you `individually build all the projects on the basis of dependency`?

Comment: And also, before checking all the supported platforms, i did try with each individual platform, but all resulting in errors.

Comment: First build the PCL then the native projects is what i meant

Comment: hey, can you take a look at my new issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55553587/xamarin-java-exe-exited-with-code-1-proguard-issue) ?