# Xamarin Java.exe exited with code 1 (Proguard Issue)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, proguard

Another day with Xamarin! Can't even build my first `Hello World` project! Not surprising, huh?

So, fresh new `Xamarin.Android` blank project. Enabled **ProGuard**, link to **SDK Assemblies Only** and went on building the project. And ***wallah!!*** There's an error!(Wait, i shouldn't be surprised, right? After all, it's Xamarin). Here's the error :

> "java.exe" exited with code 1

Double-clicking the exception opens up `Xamarin.Android.Common.Targets` file and points to the `ProGuard` tag which is as follows :

```
<Proguard
Condition="'$(AndroidEnableProguard)' == 'True' and '$(_ProguardProjectConfiguration)' != ''"
ProguardJarPath="$(ProguardJarPath)"
AndroidSdkDirectory="$(_AndroidSdkDirectory)"
JavaToolPath="$(JavaToolPath)"
ProguardToolPath="$(ProguardToolPath)"
ToolExe="$(ProguardToolExe)"
UseProguard="$(UseProguard)"
JavaPlatformJarPath="$(JavaPlatformJarPath)"
ClassesOutputDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android\bin\classes"
AcwMapFile="$(_AcwMapFile)"
ProguardCommonXamarinConfiguration="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\proguard_xamarin.cfg"
ProguardGeneratedReferenceConfiguration="$(_ProguardProjectConfiguration)"
ProguardGeneratedApplicationConfiguration="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\proguard_project_primary.cfg"
ProguardConfigurationFiles="$(ProguardConfigFiles)"
JavaLibrariesToEmbed="@(_JarsToProguard);@(_InstantRunJavaReference)"
ExternalJavaLibraries="@(AndroidExternalJavaLibrary)"
DoNotPackageJavaLibraries="@(_ResolvedDoNotPackageAttributes)"
ProguardJarOutput="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\__proguard_output__.jar"
EnableLogging="$(ProguardEnableLogging)"
DumpOutput="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\dump.txt"
PrintSeedsOutput="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\seeds.txt"
PrintUsageOutput="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\usage.txt"
PrintMappingOutput="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\mapping.txt"
ProguardInputJarFilter="$(_AndroidProguardInputJarFilter)"
/>
```

So, my best guess was that it might be a **ProGuard** related issue. So, searched up google and applied all fixes i found so far :

- Updated Android SDK
- Set Java heap size to 1G(and even 5G)
- Enabled Multi-Dex
- Updated ProGuard
- Created a new proguard.cfg file in solution(of course set `build action` to `ProGuardConfiguration` and added custom lines that are necessary.

But still, same error pointing to the same `ProGuard` tag. Now before anybody starts bashing me saying i could've messed up the proguard configuratiom file, here's the link to it:

- [ProGuard.cfg](https://pastebin.com/HYREQWkr)
- [Build Output From Visual Studio 2017](https://www69.zippyshare.com/d/Lw4QIKrC/274982/vs-Build-log.txt)

I have read that this is a very common issue in Xamarin. So, i guess, somebody might have come up with a solution that **really works!**. So, any fixes or ideas on what i might be missing?

Comment: WOW!!! 2021 THE PROBLEM IS OCCURING AGAIN... this time after i add Firebase analytics... and off course like how other Xamarin Problems... it only ME, ME ALONE in this WORLD which is having this problem!!!!!! SO FRUSTRATING!!!

Comment: @user1034912 I'm facing the same error. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @MadhavShenoy It's time to drop Xamarin, mostly because Microsoft itself dropped it. They are moving to MAUI.

Comment: @ChristopherH. Xamarin and MAUI arent different. MAUI is just an evolved version of Xamarin. And I was able to solve my problem. I ran a build in AppCenter and found out the issue. I had 2 references of Firebase messaging. I removed 1 reference and build started working again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure that the proguard file you added is NOT a Unicode text file (U+FEFF byte order mark (BOM)) as proguard will fail...
2. Enable diag. level logging for MSBuild and get the full error message.
3. Proguard is being replaced by Google's R8

If you are using the latest version of Xamarin, refer to this blog post as a start:

- [Android’s D8 dexer and R8 shrinker](https://blog.xamarin.com/androids-d8-dexer-and-r8-shrinker/)

Detailed info on the various D8/R8 project configurations can be found in the Xamarin.Android repo here:

- [This is the D8 and R8 integration specification for Xamarin.Android.](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/master/Documentation/guides/D8andR8.md)

Answer (score 0):

*Proguard* can be a bit of a pain. The usual symptom is something like

> java exited with code 1

Steps that worked for me (I had these notes stored in my solution because it just wasn't obvious). Lifted from [this site](https://hackernoon.com/configuring-proguard-and-xamarin-android-eea5a56bc316)

1. Download the latest version of *Proguard*
2. Find where your *Android SDK* is installed (something like /android-sdk/tools/proguard”). To find the sdk go to `Tools->Options->Xamarin`
3. Swap out the old version of *Proguard*, with the new one. To do this rename the current folder to something like “Proguard-pointless” and copy your new one into the tools folder.
4. Be sure to rename the folder for the new version to just be “proguard”.
5. Make sure that any configuration files are also copied across into the new *Proguard* folder. For me this was `proguard-android-optimize.txt`, `proguard-android.txt`, and `proguard-project.txt`.
6. Add a new file to the root of your *Android* project called `proguard.cfg`

   NOTE : Because *Xamarin* is smart, it saves this new file in `UTF-8` with `BOM`, **you will need to change this**. Probably best to create the file in notepad, and then include it in your program. **This is required because Proguard will not read the file unless it is in UTF-8 encoding.**
7. In VS *Right Click* on the file and select *Properties*. For Build Action, select **ProguardConfiguration**.
8. Add relevant `keep` or `dontwarn` clauses to the file without the quotes (it depends on your warnings) , for example it could be something like this...

   - "-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**"
   - "-keep class com.google.android.gms.**"
9. Once you have done those steps, try a build once again.
10. Hopefully this time it will be more successful. If it is not successful, **check your build output** and see what warnings and notes *Proguard* is giving you.

From this stage it is a matter of identifying what modifications you need to make to your custom *Proguard* file, once that works the build will be successful.

Comment: So, when i said i updated proguard and also uploaded the proguard.cfg file, what do you think i meant? I already did all of this my friend.

Comment: @zackraiyan yeah i just thought id post precisely the steps that worked for me, xamarin can be very fickle. however once you get it working its not so painful

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading Proguard to the newer version, I didn't add the files: roguard-android-optimize.txt, proguard-android.txti proguard-project.txt and that was the problem. After adding the files, the project built correctly.