# Error with Proguard - "java" exited with code 1

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I know this question might have asked a multiple times but this happened me after I updated my `Visual Studio for MAC 2019`. I am trying to archive a Xamarin Forms Android app.

When I enable Proguard I get `Error MSB6006: "java" exited with code 1. (MSB6006)`

I have tried downloading the latest version of Proguard and replacing the files in the SDK.

Following is my VS for MAC configuration.

```
=== Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac ===

Version 8.0.5 (build 9)
Installation UUID: ca67d924-4645-45bb-9a5f-c0c5881f3dc2
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
    Xamarin.Mac 5.6.0.2 (d16-0 / 040682909)

    Package version: 518010003

=== Mono Framework MDK ===

Runtime:
    Mono 5.18.1.3 (2018-08/fdb26b0a445) (64-bit)
    Package version: 518010003

=== NuGet ===

Version: 4.8.2.5835

=== .NET Core ===

Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
    2.2.4
    2.1.9
    2.1.8
    2.1.6
    2.1.2
    2.1.1
    2.0.5
    2.0.0
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.106/Sdks
SDK Versions:
    2.2.106
    2.1.505
    2.1.504
    2.1.500
    2.1.302
    2.1.301
    2.1.4
    2.0.0
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.18.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

'/Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app' not found

=== Updater ===

Version: 11

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 10.2 (14490.120)
Build 10E125

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Version: 5.8.0.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 0aa84521
Branch: d16-0
Build date: 2019-04-02 16:01:19-0400

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 12.8.0.2 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: f2248ae6
Branch: d16-0
Build date: 2019-04-23 11:59:04-0400

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 9.2.3.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Android SDK: /Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/VS Files/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        7.1 (API level 25)
        8.0 (API level 26)
        8.1 (API level 27)

SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1
SDK Platform Tools Version: 28.0.2
SDK Build Tools Version: 27.0.3

Build Information: 
Mono: mono/mono/2018-08-rc@5ac37ccd385
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d16-0@c987483
LibZipSharp: grendello/LibZipSharp/d16-1@44de300
LibZip: nih-at/libzip/rel-1-5-1@b95cf3f
MXE: xamarin/mxe/xamarin@b9cbb535
ProGuard: xamarin/proguard/master@905836d
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.26.0@325e91a
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-0@0a7edd6

=== Microsoft Mobile OpenJDK ===

Java SDK: /Users/ashish/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_8.0.25
1.8.0-25
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Android Device Manager ===

Version: 1.2.0.14
Hash: 86df26f
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-0
Build date: 2019-04-05 16:58:56 UTC

=== Xamarin Inspector ===

Version: 1.4.3
Hash: db27525
Branch: 1.4-release
Build date: Mon, 09 Jul 2018 21:20:18 GMT
Client compatibility: 1

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 800050009
Git revision: d9d7eed60cb59740ba55c04bfe9c39ac57014c12
Build date: 2019-04-26 10:08:19+00
Build branch: master
Xamarin extensions: 5efedb990d786142d3b54351c01ce867af7b7680

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.14.4
Darwin 18.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.5.0
    Mon Mar 11 20:40:32 PDT 2019
    root:xnu-4903.251.3~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

=== Enabled user installed extensions ===

Team Foundation Version Control for TFS and Azure DevOps 0.4.4.5
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55553587/xamarin-java-exe-exited-with-code-1-proguard-issue/55553679#55553679