# Xamarin: can't open app in release mode (with adb logcat)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin, and I'm trying to export my first APK.
The app runs perfectly on debug mode, and it doesn't give me a single error.
The problems arrive when I try to run in Release mode: the output console doesn't find errors, but when I try to open the app in the emulator it crashes.

Here's the adb logcat:

```
//https://pastebin.com/4rRLK45p
```

Comment: What is your Mono Linker set to? And do you have a proguard/r8 enabled? (`Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsFrameLayout"`)

Comment: My linker is set on both Sdk and User Assemblies, and I have ProGuard enabled

Comment: First try with the linker to sdk only and ProGuard off, test a release build, if that works add an exclusion to your ProGuard file to `--keep` the missing class, test a release build and keep adding any missing Java classes to your ProGuard file. Now enable the Linker with SDK & User and retest a release build. If it fails your tests, review the log and add Linker exceptions for any of your user code (usually reflection based classes/methods/members.

Comment: First try with the linker to sdk only and ProGuard off, test a release build, if that works add an exclusion to your ProGuard file to `--keep` the missing class, test a release build and keep adding any missing Java classes to your ProGuard file. Now enable the Linker with SDK & User and retest a release build. If it fails your tests, review the log and add Linker exceptions for any of your user code (usually reflection based classes/methods/members.

Comment: It works as soon as I turn Proguard off, but when I add the proguard.cfg file and I turn Proguard on again it doesn't even build (Java exits with code 1).

Comment: Point number 1 @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/55553679/4984832

Comment: Now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include this in your Proguard config:

> -keep class android.support.v7.** { public *; }

https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/proguard?tabs=macos